# How to write a multiple of a number in Python?

Tags: python

I want to test if the input is a multiple of 4 or not, and if it's not, then simply round UP the input to the nearest multiple of 4 (16, 20, 24, etc depending where the input number is).

Please have a look at the following code:

```
num = input("Enter a number: ")
if num != #a multiple of 4:
     num = round(num) #BUT round it up to the nearest multiple of 4, not just any number
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Maybe num % 4 == 0?

Comment: If you just want an expression for the next highest multiple, then `num + (-num % 4)` should work.

Answer (score 1):

the following code should work:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
if num%4 != 0:
    num = 4 * (num//4 + 1)
```

Comment: Yes, it did perfectly work. Thank you so much you've helped me tons!

Answer (score 1):

```
def round_up(number: int) -> int:
    return number + (-number % 4)
```

As an extension you could parametrise that `4` in the function to make is more generic.

Comment: Much better approach IMO. Then the test is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's an easy implementation:

```
#Create a function to round number
def round_to_multiple(number, multiple):
    return multiple * round(number / multiple)



#Implementation
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
if (num%4 != 0): #a multiple of 4:
    print(round_to_multiple(num,4))
```

Comment: This implementation doesn't work, as it doesn't round _up_ to the next multiple.

Comment: `multiple *  round(number/multiple + 1)` would work, but the round function can be replaced with the `//` operator.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. It needs to round up not down. Misread. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `module` `%` with 4 is zero to test if number is multiple of 4:

```py
num = int(input("Enter a number: ")) #add int function to convert entered value into number
if num % 4 = 0:
    print(f'{num} is multiple of 4 ')
else:
    print(f'nearest multiple of 4 of {num} is: {num + (-num % 4)}')
```

`num + (-num % 4)` is the nearest multiple of 4 that `num`.